# Application settings in <appname>.exe.config does not take effect when changing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm a little bit confused about my settings.settings file in Visual Studio 2013 . When I change settings in the .exe.config nothing happens. Only changes inside of visual Studio take effects.

I've read about that the app.config file will be copied to my bin folder and changes only take effect, when I change this file there. Okay.

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I don't need to change the settings over my code, only as an administrator from the program folder for all users.

I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

Any idea?

Comment: If you are checking this under debugger - don't. Try to run without debugger and see if there is an effect.

Comment: You need to change the .exe.config in the /bin directory not in project directory

Comment: Moreover, each time when you will run the debug, it will re-create config files and all your changes in bin folder will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

I found a possible solution here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atFsLc2wstw#t=88.132019